# Issues with Corona Storyboard Scenes

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I am trying to make a card game.. I am creating a scene, making the background,and adding an image where when the player touches he/she will be transfered to the next scene.

singlePlayer scene:

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local singlePlayer = storyboard.newScene()

local card1,card2,card3

function singlePlayer:createScene(event )
    local group = self.view
    -- body
    local bg = display.newImage("bg.png")
    bg.x = 100 ; bg.y = 50
    group:insert(bg)
end

function singlePlayer:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    local count = math.random(3)

    local storyboard = require("storyboard")
    local singlePlayer = storyboard.newScene()

    local card1,card2,card3

    function singlePlayer:createScene(event )
        local group = self.view
        -- body
        local bg = display.newImage("bg.png")
        bg.x = 100 ; bg.y = 50
        group:insert(bg)
    end

    function singlePlayer:enterScene( event )
        local group = self.view
        local count = math.random(3)

        if(count == 1) then
            card1 = display.newImage("attack.png")
            card1.x = 50 ; card1.y = 150
            group:insert(card1)
        else
            card1 = display.newImage("ability.png")
            card1.x = 50 ; card1.y = 150
            group:insert(card1)
        end

        function card1:touch(event )
            print("ok")
            if(event.phase == "ended") then
                storyboard.gotoScene("opponent_scene")
            else
            end
            -- body
        end

        card1:addEventListener("touch",card1)

        -- body
    end

    function singlePlayer:exitScene(event)
        local group = self.view
        card1:removeEventListener("touch",card1)
    end

    singlePlayer:addEventListener("createScene",singlePlayer)

    singlePlayer:addEventListener("enterScene",singlePlayer)

    singlePlayer:addEventListener("exitScene",singlePlayer)

    return singlePlayer
```

Opponent scene:

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local opponent_scene = storyboard.newScene()

function opponent_scene:createScene(event )
    print("opponent_scene created")
    -- body
end

function opponent_scene:enterScene(event )
    print("opponent_scene enter")
    local group  = self.view
    storyboard.removeScene("judge")
    local text = display.newText("Opponent's turn",150,200)
    storyboard.gotoScene("judge")
    -- body
end

function opponent_scene:exitScene(event )
    -- body
    local group = self.view
end

opponent_scene:addEventListener("createScene",opponent_scene)

opponent_scene:addEventListener("enterScene",opponent_scene)

opponent_scene:addEventListener("exitScene",opponent_scene)

return opponent_scene
```

Judge scene:

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")

local judge = storyboard.newScene()

function judge:createScene(event )
    local group = self.view
    local bg = display.newImage("destiny.png")
    storyboard.removeScene("opponent_scene")
    storyboard.gotoScene("singlePlayer")
    -- body
end

judge:addEventListener("createScene",judge)

return judge
```

Will anyone explain to me what is going on with these scenes?

All i want is to make the game wait for the player's input (touching of the card)

After two clicks on the icon, storyboard is taken to opponent scene and it just shows on the screen the text "opponent's turn". What I want to do is for the text to appear briefly and then the scene to be taken to the player scene

Comment: after two clicks on the icon, storyboard is taken to opponent scene and it just shows on the screen the text "opponent's turn". What I want to do is for the text to appear briefly and then the scene to be taken to the player scene

Comment: I reformatted your code: the indentation shows that there is something very wrong with the single player scene, like you did not paste the code correctly. Please fix. As it is, it would not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Move your scene changing code inside a delayed function with timer.delay.. Here is what I did for my game to change screen after a brief time..

```
local function onSceneTouch( self, event )
    if event.phase == "began" then

        -- write all your other code here

        -- function to change screen
        function myClosure()
           storyboard.gotoScene("opponent_scene")
        end

        -- Delay the call of closure function by 2 second (2000 milliseconds)
        timer.performWithDelay( 2000, myClosure, 1 )

    end
end
```

then call onSceneTouch function on touch of the screen

Answer (score 0):

The single player enterscene code  is wrong ,because you cant have two global function with the same name, the approach is not the right one .  why do you call create scene inside the enter frame.  suppose what you have done is correct then you should add event listeners to the  function which you create in the enterscene as did earlier

```
singlePlayer:addEventListener("createScene",singlePlayer)

singlePlayer:addEventListener("enterScene",singlePlayer)

singlePlayer:addEventListener("exitScene",singlePlayer)
```

First of all please read the documentation of the storyboard and look the sample.

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/

But i request you to use composer instead of storyboard : http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/index.html